# Cast to long datatype - BigQuery

Tags: sql, scala, hbase, google-bigquery, hbase-client

BigQuery and SQL noob here. I was going through possible data types big query supports [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types). I have a column in bigtable which is of type `bytes` and its original data type is scala `Long`. This was converted to `bytes` and stored in bigtable from my application code. I am trying to do `CAST(itemId AS integer)` (where `itemId` is the column name) in the BigQuery UI but the output of `CAST(itemId AS integer)` is 0 instead of actual value. I have no idea how to do this. If someone could point me in the right direction then I would greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT:** Adding more details
Sample `itemId` is `190007788462`

Following is the code which writes `itemId` to the big table. I have included the relevant method. Using `hbase client` to write to bigtable.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client._
def toPut(key: String, itemId: Long): Put = {
   val TrxColumnFamily = Bytes.toBytes("trx")
   val ItemIdColumn = Bytes.toBytes("itemId")
   new Put(Bytes.toBytes(key))
  .addColumn(TrxColumnFamily,
             ItemIdColumn,
             Bytes.toBytes(itemId))
```

}

Following is the entry in big table based on above code

```
ROW         COLUMN+CELL

foo         column=trx:itemId, value=\x00\x00\x00\xAFP]F\xAA
```

Following is the relevant code which reads the entry from big table in scala. This works correctly. `Result` is a `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result`

```
private def getItemId(row: Result): Long = {
  val key = Bytes.toString(row.getRow)
  val TrxColumnFamily = Bytes.toBytes("trx")
  val ItemIdColumn = Bytes.toBytes("itemId")

  val itemId =
    Bytes.toLong(row.getValue(TrxColumnFamily, ItemIdColumn))
  itemId
```

}

The `getItemId` function above correctly returns `itemId`. That's because `Bytes.toLong` is part of `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes` which correctly casts the Byte string to Long.

I am using big query UI similar to [this one](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/results/awesome-lotus-160922:bquijob_29817420_15ab02a71b9) and using `CAST(itemId AS integer)` because BigQuery doesn't have a `Long` data type. This incorrectly casts the `itemId` byte string to integer and resulting value is `0`.

Is there any way I can have a `Bytes.toLong` equivalent from `hbase-client` in BigQuery UI? If not is there any other way I can go about this issue?

Comment: Please give some examples of what `itemId` looks like and what the converted values should be.

Comment: I'm confused about this value: `\x00\x00\x00\xAFP]F\xAA`. Is the assumption that `FP]F` is interpreted as bytes as well? The rest of the value is a sequence of hex escapes. I don't see how that is supposed to be interpreted as `190007788462`.

Comment: That is not the exact itemId representation but the column is of type bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT('0x', TO_HEX(itemId)) AS INT64) AS itemId
FROM YourTable;
```

It converts the bytes into a hex string, then casts that string into an INT64. Note that the query uses standard SQL, as opposed to legacy SQL. If you want to try it with some sample data, you can run this query:

```
WITH `YourTable` AS (
  SELECT b'\x00\x00\x00\xAFP]F\xAA' AS itemId UNION ALL
  SELECT b'\xFA\x45\x99\x61'
)
SELECT CAST(CONCAT('0x', TO_HEX(itemId)) AS INT64) AS itemId
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Perfect. That worked well. How did you infer that you needed to `CONCAT('0x', TO_HEX(itemId))` ?

Comment: I've used this pattern before when doing byte manipulation. You can cast decimal strings (e.g. `1234`) to INT64, and you can also cast hexadecimal strings (e.g. `0x04D2`). Since there is a `TO_HEX` function, you can get a hexadecimal string that you can cast after prepending the `0x` :)

Comment: Interesting. Is there any pattern for for `floats` ? I tried the same pattern above but that didn't work. For example I have `price` column which is stored as bytes of a `float` type. Example `price` is `3.0` and in bigtable I see entry such as `@\x02Q\xEB\x85\x1E\xB8R` (might not be value for `3.0`)

Comment: I think it might be possible to cast to FLOAT64 as well from a hex representation, but I don't know that you'll get the expected result, and I don't think this functionality is documented. Being able to convert from a hex string to FLOAT64 is a side effect of the number parser, not something intentional I think.

Comment: Sure. I will try that